# How can I set the rect for a PDF file using PSPDFKit

Tags: pspdfkit

I'm using PSPDFKit to display PDF files fine.  However I would like all PDFs to be displayed with the same page size.  Some PDF pages are larger then others. I can use rectBoxForPage to get the current page rect, but how do I set it before it's displayed or at any other point?
    CGRect r = [document rectBoxForPage:1];

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, thanks to the developer of PSPDFKit.

Use
    pageInfo = [document pageInfoForPage:pageNum];
    pageInfo.pageRect = r;

to override the pdf page rect.